# Guardar archivos de texto en vectores

Tags: c, archivo, text

Tengo el siguiente código

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  FILE *fp1;
  FILE *fp2;
  int i,j;
  int bin[7], dec[70];
  int c;

  fp1 = fopen("bin.txt", "r");   //Abrimo  el archivo
  fp2 = fopen("dec.txt","r");

  for (i=0;i<7;i++) {                                  
    fscanf(fp1, "%d", &bin[i]);          
    printf("%d ", bin[i]);
  }

  for (j=0;j<70;j++) {                                   
    fscanf(fp2, "%d", &dec[j]);            
    printf("%d ", dec[j]);
  }

  fclose(fp1);

  return 0;
}
```

Necesito hacer unas operaciones con esos vectores, limpiarlos y después volverlos a llenar con la segunda línea del archivo de texto, pero esto solo me lee una linea.

Quisiera saber cómo leer línea por línea hasta el final del archivo.

El archivo de texto viene de la siguiente manera

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 1
0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 0 1 0
```

Comment: ¿Qué formato tienen los datos del archivo? ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Respuesta realizada a partir de la respuesta de @eferion***

Como la preguntas la centras en saber cómo ir leyendo cada fila del archivo, y tras cada lectura hacer una operación con el vector obtenido para reutilizarlo en la siguiente lectura, aquí te paso el código que pienso te sirve de estructura para lo que preguntas:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  FILE *fp1;
  int i;
  int bin[7];

  fp1 = fopen("bin.txt", "r");   //Abrimo  el archivo

  while (!feof(fp1)) 
  {
    for (i=0; i<7; ++i) {                                  
      fscanf(fp1, "%d ", &bin[i]);          
      printf("%d ", bin[i]);
    }

    /* AQUÍ HACES LA OPERACIÓN CON EL VECTOR OBTENIDO */
  }

  fclose(fp1);

  return 0;
}
```

El código supone que el archivo tiene la estructura que has indicado: filas de 7 números enteros.

No te tienes que preocupar por los saltos de línea porque `fscanf()` ignora los caracteres en blanco (espacios en blanco, tabuladores y saltos de línea) hasta que encuentra un dato del tipo indicado (en este caso entero). Pero, si te fijas, sí que hay un espacio justo después de `%d` en `fscanf()`. De esta manera te aseguras que, una vez leído el último número, ignore todos los caracteres en blanco hasta el final del archivo, evitando volver al bucle para intentar leer nuevos números cuando lo único que queda son saltos de línea o caracteres en blanco.

Comment: Le veo un pero... cuando llegas al final del fichero `feof` vale 0. Entras en el bucle de 7 y la primera lectura falla... `feof` ahora vale 1 pero no lo consultas... haces 6 lecturas mas erróneas y haces operaciones con el vector... y despues ya si compruebas `feof`

Comment: @eferion Al leer el último vector del archivo, lee en la última lectura del último número cualquier resto de caracteres en blanco (incluido los saltos de línea) que puedan quedar hasta el final del archivo. Vuelve al `while` y al comprobar `feof()` ya no vale 0 porque ha llegado al final, y se sale del bucle evitando leer datos sin haber nada más que leer.

Answer (score 2):

A diferencia de la respuesta aceptada a mi no me gusta el uso de `while(!feof(fp))`, ya que de esta forma el ultimo item se obtiene 2 veces, esto ocurre debido a que `fscanf` al leer el ultimo item no setea `EOF` en el stream, por lo que `!feof(fp)` retorna verdadero y se vuelve a ejecutar lo que esta dentro de `while` una vez mas.

Considerando lo anterior encuentro que es mejor usar la funcion `fscanf` dentro del bucle `while` aprovechandonos del hecho que `fscanf` retorna el numero de asignaciones realizadas, como en este caso se lee un entero a la vez bastaria usar algo como `while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &number) == 1)` para leer cada numero del archivo una unica vez.

Despues podrias simplemente usar un numero entero para determinar que indice del arreglo estarias leyendo, cuando este numero tenga el valor de 7 sabras que ya leiste una fila completamente, realizas tu operacion y despues seteas el numero a 0.

Considerando lo anteriormente dicho, escribi este codigo que probe y funciona perfectamente para lo que deseas hacer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  FILE *fp;
  int i, number;
  int array[7];

  fp = fopen("bin.txt", "r");

  i = 0;

  while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &number) == 1) {
    printf("%d ", number);
    array[i] = number;

    i++;

    if (i == 7) {
      printf("Realizar operacion aqui\n");
      i = 0;
    }
  }

  fclose(fp);

  return 0;
}
```

Al ejecutarlo obtienes esta salida:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 Realizar operacion aqui
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 Realizar operacion aqui
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 Realizar operacion aqui
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 Realizar operacion aqui
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 Realizar operacion aqui
0 0 0 0 1 0 1 Realizar operacion aqui
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 Realizar operacion aqui
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 Realizar operacion aqui
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 Realizar operacion aqui
0 0 0 1 0 0 1 Realizar operacion aqui
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 Realizar operacion aqui
```

Creo que no hace falta mencionar que donde puse `printf("Realizar operacion aqui\n")` es donde iria tu operacion vectorial.

Saludos y suerte!

Answer (score 1):

Para leer línea por línea tienes que verificar si has llegado al final del fichero... cosa que puedes conseguir con `feof()`:

```
while( 1 )
{
  for(i=0;i<7;i++){                                  
    fscanf(fp1, "%d", &bin[i]);
    if( feof(fp1) ) break; // Despues de la lectura, ojo!!!

    printf("%d ", bin[i]);
  }
}
```

Aunque, por otro lado, decir que ese código es C++ es mucho decir. Realmente tu algoritmo es C... pero compatible con C++. Para decir que el código es C++ yo esperaría encontrar `std::ifstream` en vez de `FILE*`:

```
std::ifstream file("bin.txt");
file.open();

if(!file.is_open())
{
  // error
}

while( true )
{
  for( int i=0; i<7; i++ )
  {
    if( !file >> bin[i] ) break;
    std::cout << bin[i] << ' ';
  }
}
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que no elimina el salto de línea? `fscanf` considera como caracteres en blanco: espacio en blanco, tabulador y salto de línea. A los tres los trata por igual al ignorarlos, de modo que si se ejecuta `fscanf("%d", &d)`, desde el punto donde se encuentre en el archivo va a ignorar todos los caracteres en blanco hasta que encuentre un entero. No hace falta poner un espacio `" %d"`. Si estuviese leyendo un carácter con `%c` entonces sí q es relevante, pq `%c` lee un carácter sea cual sea y poniendo el espacio obliga a ignorar caracteres en blanco hasta encontrar un carácter

Comment: @CarlosA.Gómez cierto... es lo que tiene responder con prisas. Gracias por el aviso

Comment: no entendi muy bien lo que me quieres decir. agregue un fracmento del txt para hacerme entender mejor

Comment: @SebastianMateusVillegas si conoces el numero de lineas es tan facil como meter tu lectura actual dentro de otro bucle para leerlas todas. Si ignoras ese dato tienes que leer hasta que llegas al final del fichero... pero solo sabrás que has alcanzado ese límite cuando hagas la primera lectura errónea... por eso `feof` se consulta después de intentar leer.

Comment: @eferion Iba a comentarte las modificaciones en tu primer código, pero me estaba extendiendo demasiado y no me entraba aquí, por lo tanto lo he puesto en una nueva respuesta.

Comment: @eferion Te cito en mi respuesta. :)